# How to validate a configuration property only if a certain profile is active?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to expect a property not to be null, only if a certain profile is active?

```java
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
@Validated
public class SampleProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String sample1;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private MoreProperties more = new MoreProperties()


    @Data
    public static class MoreProperties {

        @NotNull // ← This should not be null only if the prod profile is active
        private String sample2;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to implement the `Condition` class and write your logic there. I am afraid there is no clean way to do this

Answer (score 2):

How about using two `@ConfigurationProperties` classes.

One like this:

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
public class SampleProperties {

  @NotNull
  private String sample1;

  // Getters + Setters
}
```

And one like this

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
public class SamplePropertiesForProfile extends SampleProperties {

  @NotNull // ← This should not be null only if the prod profile is active
  private String sample2;

  // Getters + Setters
}
```

And using these classes as beans only if the correct profile is active like this.
The `@EnableConfigurationProperties` provides the `@ConfigurationProperties` class as bean.
I prefer this over the `@Component` annotation on the `@ConfigurationProperties` class, because it's guaranteed that the bean is only created if it is required.
I see `@ConfigurationProperties` as a 'dumb' container of properties that does not know anything about their usage and therefore it can't know when its required and when it is not.

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("!yourDesiredProfile")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SampleProperties.class)
public class SampleNotProfileConfiguration {

  private readonly SampleProperties sampleProperties;

  @Autowired
  public SampleNotProfileConfiguration(SampleProperties sampleProperties){
    this.sampleProperties = sampleProperties;
  }

  // Configure your beans with the properties required for this profile
}


@Configuration
@Profile("yourDesiredProfile")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SamplePropertiesForProfile .class)
public class SampleProfileConfiguration {

  private readonly SamplePropertiesForProfile samplePropertiesForProfile ;

  @Autowired
  public SampleProfileConfiguration (SamplePropertiesForProfile samplePropertiesForProfile ){
    this.samplePropertiesForProfile = samplePropertiesForProfile ;
  }

  // Configure your beans with the properties required for this profile
}
```

Doing this you have an explicit configuration for each profile with explicit configuration properties.
Even the name `@ConfigurationProperties` already states that this class contains `properties` of a `configuration`. These properties should match the requirements of the `@Configuration` class.
Therefore if a bean should be configured in a different way for a given profile it should be another `@Configuration` which then requires another explicit `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Can't verify this solution at the moment but for my understanding of `@ConfigurationProperties` this should work and looks more clean to me than mixing properties of different profiles.

Comment: Yes, declaring two beans, one activated when a profile is present and the other one in its absence would work, but I am afraid that does not solve my problem per se, i.e. a configuration properties bean with complex fields (e.g. the `more` field here) that need to be validated only if a given profile is active.

Comment: Otherwise, I could have simply defined two beans like [this](https://gist.github.com/behrangsa/61f60b0e70c6d3e2fec3f2cd432df517).

Comment: Hm, I think i don't get the point why it should be necessary to have a property inside your configuration properties that isnt required whenever your configuration properties is required.
This looks like an architectural flaw to me.
I think the only way to achieve this is to write a custom Validator that checks for the profile and returns true for all profiles that don't require this property.
Feels wrong to me.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, Spring has a `KafkaProperties` class that has nested complex properties for producers and consumers, even though an app might only be a consumer and not a producer, rather than having `KafkaConsumerProperties` and `KafkaProducerProperties`. `KafkaProperties` works because it is not validated. If they wanted to validate the properties they would have encountered a similar problem.

Comment: That's true. But just because they did it, it's not good. I love what the spring boot team does, but they are humans aswell.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it is acceptable just because they have done it. I genuinely don't think it is an architectural flaw. Sure, if Spring does not have the necessarily tools and classes to allow validating a sub-graph of properties based on active profiles, it makes sense to split the properties between multiple classes. But without generalizing things, why do you think the `KafkaProperties` class is the symptom of an architectural flaw?

Comment: Why should a Kafka-Configuration, that is only configuring a producer, getting consumer properties?
This could tempt to use some properties used for consumer for the producers, too (what i consider a bad thing).
I like separation of responsibilities.

Comment: Btw spring has the tools to do so: The validators. As already mentioned you could write a custom validator. Something like `@NotNullOnProfiles(profilesToCheck = {profileA, profileB})` which then checks if the current active profile is contained in the profiles to check. If not the validator returns always true. If contained it checks on null.